# Using NULL in WHERE of LookupOrderedRows()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Project: I want to add AMPScript to an email template that will stop emails from being sent if the same email is already scheduled in the future. This is to prevent marketing users from accidentally sending the same email twice. Sadly happens with some regularity.

I've come up with a workable solution, but am having trouble using logic if value is NULL in Lookuporderedrows(). Is this possible? Any alternate approaches are appreciated :)

What I want to do:

```
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("_Job",0,"JobID Desc","EmailID",_EmailID,"DeliveredTime",NULL)
```

Even though the DeliveredTime in this case is equal to NULL, the script errors and does not work.

Here is my full script:

```
%%[
SET @lookupKey = _EmailID
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("_Job",0,"JobID Desc","EmailID",@lookupKey,"Category","my tracking")
IF (RowCount(@rows) > 0) THEN
    SET @row = Row(@rows,1)
    SET @JobID = Field(@row, 'JobID')
    SET @EmailID = Field(@row, 'EmailID')
    SET @SchedTime = Field(@row, 'SchedTime')
    SET @EmailName = Field(@row, 'EmailName')
    SET @DeliveredTime = Field(@row, 'DeliveredTime')
    SET @Now = Now()
    SET @DDiff = DateDiff(@Now,@SchedTime, 'MI')
    IF (@DDiff > 0 AND IsNull(@DeliveredTime) == TRUE) THEN
        SET @warning = Concat("WARNING: ", @emailName, " is already scheduled with a Job ID of ", @JobID, " scheduled for ", @SchedTime,". Cancel the previous send or duplicate the email.")
        RaiseError(@warning)
    ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting. However, be advised that this solution will still cost you the email super messages for the subscribers, even if the mail isn't sent as ampscript is rendered during the send process.

Comment: Is this something that would need to be constantly updated in real time? or could you use a source for your lookup that would be refreshed every hour or similar scheduled rate? ALSO - this will be on a cloudpage/script activity, correct?

Comment: This is going to be included in the code of the saved email template. So it will be run with every send or preview and test. The equivalent of what I want to do in SQL is

`SELECT *
FROM '_Job' job
WHERE
job.EmailID = [_EmailID]
AND job.DeliveredTime is NULL`